# Javascript - typo

Tags: javascript

I am using a jquery plugin that uses some variable, assume 'parent' and comment_text are simple string variables

```
var text = '<input type="button" class="waveButton" value="" onclick="addSubmit(this,'+parent+')" /> '
```

The function addSubmit() process just fine. but if I add this :

```
var text = '<input type="button" class="waveButton" value="'+comment_text+'" onclick="addSubmit(this,'+parent+')" /> '
```

it doesn't work anymore. I suppose it is a typo because my IDE shows colors as if it didn't recognize that addSubmit() is a function

Somebody has an idea ?

Comment: Why "typo"?  How exactly does it not work?  What are "comment_text" and "parent"?

Comment: And what plugin? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `parent`? If you add it to a string it will get cast to a string. You'll likely get `[object Object]` which will give you a syntax error.

```
addSubmit(this, [object Object]) // <-- syntax error
```

Comment: Then you need to surround it in `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it should work. But do make sure the variable "comment_text" doesn't contain any special characters that would affect the html code.